# ~3400 ppm/C resistor replacement/substitute?

Tags: resistors, analog, temperature, vco, synthesizer

I am working on reviving an old synth design (Transcendent 2000 for those interested) and the VCO and VCF both rely on high ppm/C resistors to compensate for temperature changes. I can include the schematic below, but the two values are 820R and 870R copper wound resistors (3900 ppm/C). They are wired in series to respective 130R metal oxide resistors. The desired temperature coefficient is 3400 ppm/C. I looked for replacements but they seem to be in short supply and in the wrong value. Is there a way I can replace both with modern parts? I saw in one thread a way of using a thermistor, but the method seemed to be incomplete.

VCO:
[image: VCO]
VCF:
[image: VCF]

Comment: Schematic failed to attach

Comment: Akaneohm +3300ppm resistors are available online

Answer (score 3):

There are available nickel resistors which are ~+4100ppm/K, sold as linear temperature dependent resistors. You can put a low-tempco resistor in series to slightly reduce that tempco.

Similarly, platinum SMT elements are available in 100\$\Omega\$ ohms, 500 \$\Omega\$ and 1k\$\Omega\$ and have a tempco of about +3880ppm/K near room temperature.

Sounds like you're working with log/antilog circuits. It's probably worth doing a deep dive into the math and simulations to make sure you get the right parts.

Comment: They are both log circuits. What formulas should I use to calculate the tempco? I'm still pretty new to this. I forgot to add the schematics, they are above now.